# store domino document content in a data attribute of a div in xpages for use in Morris.js

Tags: javascript, json, xpages

We are trying to use BootCards with XControls for a new mobile UI on our business xpages applications.

Now when we pick a document from the list built from a domino view we would like to store some data into data attributes of some divs for later use in Morris.js charts in client side JS.

Our code for trying this does not work at all in xPages, we get errors for type conversions or refences.

Can some one provide a way for attaching some javascript object into the data attribute of a div in the xpage and get that attribute read, convert to a Json for using it in a Morris.js chart in client side JS?

Comment: It would be useful to see the code you're trying, to see if it's a coding error or whether an alternate approach may be preferable.

Comment: Also, storing JavaScript objects in data attributes wouldn't be an approach I would take. Why not store it in some JavaScript object or somewhere on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting errors when trying to attach it to an XPages Div control? If so, using a Computed Field control and set the content to be HTML to output a normal HTML div to the web page.